# AJAX Post to handler functions in Razor pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, datatables, razor-pages

So the situation is such:

I am using data-tables in my .cshtml file. I have managed to add records via a modal but the issue is when i want to populate a modal in order to edit the data from a row. I do not wish to fetch data from the row but instead do a Ajax request to fetch the data. Below shows the structure of my table

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive display nowrap" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Roles</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var user in Model.Users)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                <td>@user.LastName</td>
                <td>@user.UserName</td>
                <td>@user.Email</td>
                <td>@user.status</td>
                <td>
                    @{ if (user.Roles.Contains("SuperAdmin"))
                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-danger">SA</span> }
                        else if (user.Roles.Contains("Admin"))
                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-danger">ADMIN</span> }
                        else if (user.Roles.Contains("Moderator"))
                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-warning">MOD</span> }
                        else if (user.Roles.Contains("Basic"))
                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-success">BASIC</span> } 
                        
                        }
                </td>
                 
                <td>
                        @{ if (user.Roles.Contains("SuperAdmin"))
                                        {
                            <span class="badge badge-warning">Locked</span> }
                        else
                        {

                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark details" id="useredit" data-id="@user.UserId">Edit</button>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/UserRoles" asp-route-userId="@user.UserId">Manage Roles</a> } 
                        }
                </td>
            </tr>}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When i click on the edit button the follow code gets executed

```
$("button.details").on('click', function () {
        console.log({ "id": $(this).attr("data-id") });
        var userid = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Identity/Account/Users?handler=UsersAsJson",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: { id:userid },
                contentType: "json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (regions) {
                    console.log(regions)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
    });
```

And this is the handler function below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUsersAsJsonAsync(string? id)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id passed",id);
        
        
        return new JsonResult(id);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how do we pass the id from the ajax request into the handler function? cause at the moment its not posting to the OnPostUsersAsJsonAsync function.

Also note i have tried getJSON without any success.

Comment: [this post](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/AjaxRequest) is for inline ajax requests, but it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you do not have a form,be sure you have added token like below:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark details" id="useredit" data-id="@user.UserId">Edit</button>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Change your js like below:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("button.details").on('click', function () {
            console.log({ "id": $(this).attr("data-id") });
            var userid = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Identity/Account/Users?handler=UsersAsJson",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: { id: userid },
                //contentType: "json; charset=utf-8",  //remove this line
                success: function (regions) {
                    console.log(regions)
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");  //be sure add this line
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: As a side note... `console.log({ "id": $(this).attr("data-id") });` could be replaced with `console.log({ "id": $(this).data("id") });`